# Spring Security redirects to login page again after successful authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I wrote a small spring security oauth provider(App id) spring boot starter and trying to test it https://github.com/yharish991/appid-spring-boot-starter

This is how my security configuration looks like

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/login**", "/user").authenticated()
         .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
             .permitAll()
             .and()
             .oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

The problem is after successful authentication, the app is always redirected to the login page again and the Principal object is always null

Comment: I had a similar problem with keycloak, but it was relating to integration with redis and session caching. Do you have any other technologies included?

Comment: I'm not using any other technologies, trying to integrate a simple spring boot oauth2

Comment: Do not keep resource `/login` as authenticated resource. Remove that antMatcher in `.authenticated() `

Comment: Use this `.antMatchers("/user").authenticated() .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()`

Comment: The problem was with the redirecturi, i did not configure it properly..